# Alternative for .click() method in Firefox

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-browser, click, dom-events

I have a `href` from which I am giving out a popup, and I want to activate this in my body's `onload`. I use `document.getElementbyId("myelement").click()` which works fine in IE but Firefox doesn't support it. I know that `.click()` will not be supported by Firefox , but I don't have any other way to do it.

Can you please suggest a workaround that works in IE as well as in Firefox?

Comment: *I know that `.click()` will not be supported by Firefox* Some reference would be nice...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do as Alsciende suggests, or if you need the event object you can use `dispatchEvent` to trigger an event handler:

```
document.body.onload = function () {
    var element = document.getElementById("element");

    if ("click" in element)
        element.click();
    else if ("dispatchEvent" in element) {
        var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}
```

It's sometimes useful to use a framework, such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com), to handle these sorts of browser inconsistencies for you.  More or less, the same code in jQuery would be:

```
$('#element').click();
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a function that opens the popup, and use this function in the body onload handler as well as in the link onclick handler.

```
function openPopup() {
  window.open("...");
  return false;
}

<body onload="openPopup()">
 ...
 <a id="myelement" href="#" onclick="openPopup()">...</a>
 ...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just so that it helps someone , i have seen this in use in many code, but can't guarantee if it works in your case , following is what i have tried too -

'leftclick .divname' : '_functionname',

Not sure . but this might be using something that underscore js has to offer . I am using this in a backbone app which has underscore js support .